# How to deploy Azure Python Web App With FTP Using PowerShell?

Tags: git, powershell, azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service

I have a PowerShell script that creates a web app on Azure. The script also gets the files in my folder and uploads them using FTP. I also see that the files are updated, which is great. My code is a Python Rest API.

My problem is that the "deployment" phase isn't running.
If for example I use git to deploy, then there's an automatic deployment, that looks like this:

```html
remote: Preparing deployment for commit id '48a4891b08'.
remote: Generating deployment script.
remote: Running deployment command...
remote: Handling python deployment.
```

Using ftp this **doesn't happen** and new python packages aren't installed.

**So, Is there a way to signal the web app to deploy?**

Here's a snippet of my code:

```html
# Create a resource group
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Location $location

# Create an App Service plan in `Free` tier.
New-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Name $webappName -Location $location -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Tier Free

# Create a web app.
New-AzureRmWebApp -Name $webappName -Location $location -AppServicePlan $webappName `
-ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

# Get publishing profile for the web app
[xml]$xml = (Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingProfile -Name $webappName `
-ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
-OutputFile null)

# Extract connection information from publishing profile
$username = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@userName").value
$password = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@userPWD").value
$url = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@publishUrl").value

# Upload files recursively 
Set-Location $appDirectory
$webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $appDirectory -Recurse | Where-Object{!($_.PSIsContainer)}
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $relativepath = (Resolve-Path -Path $file.FullName -Relative).Replace(".\", "").Replace('\', '/')
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri("$url/$relativepath")
    "Uploading to " + $uri.AbsoluteUri
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $file.FullName)
} 
$webclient.Dispose()
```